# Spark: Why does some tasks have zero input size, How does input size get calculated?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running 2 spark jobs one with 1 executors and other with 8 executors.

*A (1 executor)*

```
spark-submit --class com.SmallfilesResearchProcess --master yarn-cluster --queue xxx --executor-memory 1g --driver-memory 6g --num-executors 1 --conf spark.executor.cores=8 --conf spark.logLineage=true /tmp/hadoop-tools-1.2-SNAPSHOT-spark.jar coalesce.num.partitions=32
```

*Here are the results for case A from spark UI*

```
Executor ID ▴   Address         Task Time   Total Tasks     Failed Tasks    Succeeded Tasks     Input Size / Records
1               machine:xxx     2.0 min        32             0              32                 404.5 MB / 525572

Total Time Across All Tasks: 2.0 min
Locality Level Summary: Node local: 1; Rack local: 31
Input Size / Records: 404.5 MB / 525572
```

*B (8 executors)*

```
spark-submit --class com.SmallfilesResearchProcess --master yarn-cluster --queue xxx --executor-memory 1g --driver-memory 6g --num-executors 8 --conf spark.executor.cores=8 --conf spark.logLineage=true /tmp/hadoop-tools-1.2-SNAPSHOT-spark.jar coalesce.num.partitions=32
```

*Here are the results for case B from spark UI*

```
Executor ID ▴   Address         Task Time   Total Tasks     Failed Tasks    Succeeded Tasks     Input Size / Records
1               machine:xxxx    22 s        4                   0               4                   37.0 MB / 63106
2               machine:xxxx    25 s        4                   0               4                   0.0 B / 64068
3               machine:xxxx    27 s        4                   0               4                   0.0 B / 65045
4               machine:xxxx    22 s        4                   0               4                   38.1 MB / 64255
5               machine:xxxx    27 s        5                   0               5                   52.3 MB / 82091
6               machine:xxxx    22 s        5                   0               5                   49.1 MB / 79232
7               machine:xxxx    19 s        3                   0               3                   0.0 B / 48337
8               machine:xxxx    22 s        3                   0               3                   0.0 B / 59438


Total Time Across All Tasks: 2.8 min
Locality Level Summary: Node local: 4; Rack local: 28
Input Size / Records: 176.5 MB / 525572
```

Question 1: **How is the input size calculated, I was thinking it should be the same considering the records is same for both the cases?** 176.5 MB in case B against 405MB in case A.

Question 2: **Why is the input size 0 B for some of the tasks in case B?**

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue with spark. Also, the tasks with 0.0B input runs forever and never completes. Any suggestions on how to debug or fix it?

Comment: Could you give more details about your code? I can't reproduce it.